# Tile mapping fps optimization

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am developing my first VB.net game. Im using windows forms and system.drawgraphics to do it. I draw a bunch of squares with a textures in the screen but i am getting about 30 fps in my beefy i3 7100 + rx 480 system. Is there anywaw to manipulate the gpu to draw the graphics instead of the cpu or is is possible to optimize? I'm just in basic/interm. programmer in VB. The game is just in a mannualy controll fase(you can just edit the map). Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This type of question isn't correct for this site. It is mainly for people with a specific problem with code they have written and can't solve the problem. As your code seems to work, you may be better having a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ But please read their rules. General programming questions like this don't belong here I'm afraid. (Incidentally learning about DirectX may help)

Comment: DirectX or OpenGL is the way to go. The `System.Drawing` members use GDI+ which is processor-based. -- I've been down this road as well, believe me: there is no other way than to learn a new API.